# three.js JSON Model Vertex Colors not shown in editor

Tags: javascript, c#, json, 3d, three.js

I am writing a JSON exporter but am having issues saving out color information for the vertices of my mesh objects.  Here is what the output of an isocahedron looks like: https://gist.github.com/fraguada/69d523af7f75049db39e

Here is an image describing what I see in the program used to create the object (left) and in the threejs editor (right): https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TCCF.jpg

If I would have to guess the issue, I'd say it is the way I am passing the color to JSON.  I get access to the RGB values of each mesh vertex and convert the values to an int:

```
public int ColorToInt(Color color)
{
     string c = color.R.ToString("X2") + color.G.ToString("X2") + color.B.ToString("X2");
     return Convert.ToInt32(c, 16);
}
```

Checking the color output, things seem ok.  The first vertex color I process on this model is 127,255,0 (R,G,B,) which translates to 8388352 or 7fff00.  I assume I need the 8388352 representation in the JSON file as this is the format used in the examples I've looked at.

Based on the JSON file, is there anything obvious that would make the vertex colors not work in the threejs editor?  I've tried some other files (not generated by my exporter) and they all have the vertex colors showing.

Thanks.

Comment: Your file looks good. Try 1. drag and drop the file onto the Editor, 2. set VertexColors, 3. close the window, and 4. re-open the window.

Comment: I closed the editor and reopened.  My file was already loaded as were the vertex color options I set before.  The mesh looks as I expected, vertex colors come through: http://i.imgur.com/2aGURbp.jpg 
I mostly use the editor to check that the JSON output is correct, so this verifies that at least the color info is working.  Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: So, the problem is a bug in the Editor. Would you like to file a [bug report](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md).?

Comment: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5982